# error: no matching function for call to 'strcmp'

Tags: c++

I am brand new to c++ and I'm trying to compare two strings using `strcmp`, but it seems that my code, `string s(1, line[i]);` does not convert the character line[i] into a string properly. Can someone please explain to me how I can do this correctly? Thanks:)

Here is my code.

```
string s(1, line[i]);

if (strcmp(s, ".") == 0) {
    newline = newline + ".";
}
else if (strcmp(s, argc[4]) == 0) {
    newline = newline + argc[5];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You tag the question with `C++` don't you? Why not using string comparison directly?

```
string s(1, line[i]);

if (s == string(".")) { ... }
else if (s == string(argc[4])) { ... }
```

Comment: There's no need to construct temporary strings here, you can compare `s == "."` and `s == argc[4]`. There are `operator==` overloads for `const char*`.

Comment: @Blastfurnace I intentionally place the constructor there for OP to understand more easily since he seems to be newbie in C++.

Answer (score 1):

`strcmp` is a C function from the 70's.

`string` is a C++ class from the '80s.

In general you can't count on C functions to support C++ classes, and `strcmp` is no exception. C does not know what a `string` is.

Fortunately `string` doesn't care. It has [comparison functions built right in](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp), one of which supports the `==` operator.

```
if (s == ".") {
    newline = newline + ".";
}
else if (s == argc[4]) {
    newline = newline + argc[5];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`strcmp` need `const char*` parameter, but 's' is a string
so `strcmp(s.c_str(), ".")` is the right way to use

Comment: `s == "."` is the right way to use it, the use of `strcmp` is unnecessary. No harm in pointing out the correct way to use `strcmp`, but your answer would be better if it also mentioned the _correct_ way to do this.